# Image Preprocessing

Tags: cnn, image-preprocessing, image

I'm working on a use case where I need to pre process the image for my AIML model evaluation and I want to count all black pixels in RGB image.

Instead of iterating rows*column, I'm looking for some vector based approach for this evaluation.
Please suggest.

Comment: If you are using python library `numpy`, you don't even need to iterate on rows and columns. When you read the image using numpy, it will become numpy array. Filtering on numpy array will give you what you want. It will automatically filter on every value.

Comment: Just map on a threshold to 1 and then sum it. Numpy will take care of Vectorization. Just use its inbuild functions.

Comment: Thanks. I have implmented it and sharing further on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I did this implementation,

```
#img = [w,h,c] numpy array of image
out = img == [0,0,0]
np.sum(np.sum(out,axis=1) == 3)
```

Its working. Let me know in case we can optimized it further.